# IntelliJ is complaining about OSGi reference attribute

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, osgi

I have an `OSGi` reference in my `spring-context.xml` cofiguration file. When I specify:

```
<osgi:reference id="cxfInboundLoggingInterceptor" interface="com.groupgti.esb.cxf.interceptors.MessageLoggerInbound" />
```

`IntelliJ` says that: `Attribute id is not allowed here`. My `osgi` prefix is pointing to this schema: `xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"`

And schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
```

From `Spring` `OSGi` [documentation](http://www.springsource.org/osgi/specification):

> *The `<osgi:reference>` element is used to define a local bean that acts as a proxy to an OSGi service (or set of services). The only required
>   attributes are id (which defines the name of the local bean) and
>   interface (which defines the fully qualified name of the interface
>   that the target service is registered under).*

So I see that id is required, but why then `IntelliJ` is complaining about it?

Comment: I spent a couple hours trying to figure out the same problem but failed. I suspect it's an IDEA bug and now I just ignore it.

Comment: Can an inspection be disabled (any idea which one?) to suppress these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that osgi xsd does

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool"/>
```

and for me they are not found. But even when you set them up it does not seem to work.

You probably need to file a bugreport for IntelliJ at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

I've created the ticket to this bug in [JetBrains Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105450)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to qualify the id attribute: xml:id?